# Implementing multiple D3 layout on same page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I tried to add multiple D3 graphs on same page i.e. Pie Chart, Bar Graph and a tree layout using different data in either CSV or JSON format. But I am not able to implement all of these 3 graphs on the same page. When I link more than 1 layout on a same page, I get a blank page.

I tried to append each chart in a different div using following HTML and JS

**HTML**

```
<div id="piediv"></div>
<div id="bardiv"></div>
<div id="treediv"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var svg = d3.select("#piediv").append("svg")
var svg = d3.select("#bardiv").append("svg")
var svg = d3.select("#treediv").append("svg")
```

All of the **JS** lines above are in their respective individual JS files viz. pie.js, bar.js and tree.js

Comment: you just overwrote your svg variables twice

Comment: @thatOneGuy Although that might break some other code, it should not result in a blank page as reported by OP.

Comment: @EricCartmann Please set up a [mcve] demonstrating the effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all i suggest you to declare svg variables with a different names.

I made a fiddle for you with a similar problem; more in details, I have created two donut charts in the same page in this way:

I have created two different `<div>` with two different ids

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="chart2"></div>
```

and I also created two different svgs (with different name)

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var svg2 = d3.select("#chart2").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g7k9pfd/) for more details

Let me know.